# Need for, or alternative to, 'factual' in the phrase 'factual findings'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I recently encountered the term **factual findings**, with *factual* defined as "based on research and analysis". I have seen *findings of fact* and *fact finding* many times, but never **factual findings**.

Questions raised by the use of **factual findings** include:

> Are there *findings* that are not *factual*?

> Are there *findings* not "based on research and analysis"? Is this side definition really necessary?

Bottom line: Is the word *factual* necessary? If an adjective such as *factual* is necessary to distinguish between different kinds of findings (I'm ruling out *preliminary findings* here), does it require a side definition? If *factual* does require a side definition, is there a single-word alternative whose meaning is so obvious that it doesn't require a side definition?

Comment: In contrast to ***fanciful*** *findings*, perhaps? ("What did you find?" "I saw a footprint in the hallway, and found that a fairy had paid me a visit.") The definition of [*finding*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finding) does not necessitate that the results be factual, so it makes sense that there would be such a qualification in certain contexts where that assumption is erroneous.

Comment: @JasonBassford Good points. The context here is accident investigations with the audience being those conducting them or having an interest in their results.

Comment: It would be assumed that an accident investigation would produce factual findings. (Otherwise, anybody could simply guess what happened and not investigate at all.) So, it certainly seems redundant in that situation. But I can also imagine dialogue like the following from a show like the *X-Files*: "I don't want your wild speculations! I'm looking for factual findings." Even in the context of a something that would presume conclusions based on reality, somebody could use *factual* as an emphasized counterpoint to something else said just before. Redundant doesn't necessarily mean undesired.

Comment: (Not to mention that "I'm looking for findings" actually sounds strange to me. That particular construction seems to need an adjective.)

Comment: Possibly "well supported findings" as opposed to findings which result from sloppy, incomplete research, prejudice and guesswork.

Comment: @BoldBen Good thought. Thanks!

Comment: How about *empirical*?  Still has the redundancy problem.